# How to call a function within login_redirect add_filter

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having a hard time calling a function within the code:

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

For example if I have a function in my plugin called:

```
function my_test() {
   if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
   } else {
    echo 'Welcome, visitor!';
   }   
}
```

When I try to use that function inside add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 ); for example:

```
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    my_test(); // <--- do not trigger the first time
    exit();
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Any Idea why?

Comment: After a login form you should add a session did you add a session on your code? If so can you update your post?

Comment: Your code works, but the echo is not visually visible. When I write your text to a log file, it will be there. Of course it depends on what your ultimate intention is.

Comment: I have updated my code: 
So the function fire but is_user_logged_in() doesn't trigger causing my function to always be false;